# How to merge two video parts and get a playable video file using Python?

Tags: subprocess

Here, I actually wants to merge two strings out1 & out2 (which contains the first and second 30sec long video data) and write that to a file. So that I will get a 1min long playable video file. But what I am getting is the first 30sec video only. How should I edit this code to achieve that ? Please help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
import subprocess,os

ffmpeg_command1 = ["ffmpeg", "-i", "PATH/connect.webm", "-vcodec", "copy", "-ss", "00:00:00", "-t", "00:00:30","-f", "webm", "pipe:1"]

p1 = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out1, err = p1.communicate()

ffmpeg_command2 = ["ffmpeg", "-i", "PATH/connect.webm","-vcodec", "copy", "-ss", "00:00:31", "-t", "00:00:30","-f", "webm", "pipe:1"]

p2 = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command2,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out2, err1 = p2.communicate()

string = out1 + out2

fname = "PATH/final.webm"

fp = open(fname,'wb')

fp.write(string)

fp.close()
```

Please help me. I struck.

Comment: @sean Brother, There I asked how to merge two video files. But here I asked how to merge strings containing that video data. So that we can achieve without creating and reading files. And for that I unfortunately got a down vote :(.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concat two videos with ffmpeg, it works like that:

```
ffmpeg -vcodec copy -isync -i \
"concat:file1.mp4|file2.mp4|...|fileN.mp4" \
outputfile.mp4
```

Comment: I did that and it works fine brother .Here I got the answer for that already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311708/how-to-join-two-video-files-using-python. But what I want to do is not to read two files and concatenate. Instead I want to merge two strings which contains the video data without creating files.

Answer (score 0):

```
#coding=utf-8
import os

#Function to create a file list in the folder
import os
s = os.sep
path = r"F:\folder_mp4_files\temp"
def create_file_list(path):
    return_list = []
    for filenames in os.walk(path):
        for file_list in filenames:
            for file_name in file_list:
                if file_name.endswith((".mp4")):
                    return_list.append(path+s+file_name)
    return return_list

alist = create_file_list(path)
tsString = '|'.join([i.replace('.mp4','.ts') for i in alist])
print(tsString)
# mp4 converts to ts
for i in alist:
    noExtension = i.replace('.mp4','')
    # batch processing
    os.system("ffmpeg -i %s -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb %s.ts" % (i,noExtension))
# Remove used mp4 files
for i in alist:
    os.remove(i)
os.system("""ffmpeg -i concat:"{0}" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -absf aac_adtstoasc {1}""".format(tsString, alist[0]))
# Remove used ts files
for i in alist:
    os.remove(i.replace('.mp4','.ts'))
```